# What's the difference between using Cloud Functions Firebase Realtime Database Triggers and Admin SDK Firebase Realtime Database Read Event Types?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

```
functions.database.ref('/path')
.onCreate((snap, context) => {

}
```

vs

```
ref
.on("child_added", function(snapshot, prevChildKey) {
}
```

To me they look like the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When registering the `on("child_added"` in your second snippet, you need a node script that stays active in order to receive those events. If you kill the node script, you will stop receiving `child_added` events.

Your first snippet would be registered on Google Cloud Functions, which handles the activation/deactivation of the Node.js container for you. In fact, it handles scaling it up and down with the number of events coming in.

So while the code inside of the methods may do the exact same thing, they are subtly different in scaling and cost:

- The code you run on Cloud Functions is auto-scaling from zero to any peak load. Its cost is directly linear to the number of invocations and the time that each of those take.
- The code you run on your own Node.js environment on the other hand has a fixed capacity at a fixed cost (the cost it takes to keep your Node.js environment active).

Comment: thanks for your response Puff, so when the server is idle, if an event happens, the first snippet will be triggered but the second one will not right?

Comment: The second snippet is not in any way related to Cloud Functions at the moment. But if you'd embed it into a Cloud Function, it'd only keep listening for as long as the Cloud Function is active. In general: using `on()` inside Cloud Functions is an anti-pattern: while there are some valid use-cases for the combination, most often I see it, it's a mistake.